# no bean named "myController" available

Tags: spring-boot

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155)
    at sumit.springframework.sfgpetclinic.SfgDiApplication.main(SfgDiApplication.java:17)
```

I have tried using ComponentScan and Configuration but nothing works.
this is my repo  - https://github.com/jerry2132/sfg-di

Comment: Questions must be self-contained. No external links. [Tour], [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your file name and class name is not the same.

> src/main/java/sumit/springframework/sfgpetclinic/controller/Mycontroller.java

Here it should be;

> src/main/java/sumit/springframework/sfgpetclinic/controller/MyController.java

Other than that, it's looks fine, this should work properly.

Make sure your packages and file names are well-structured.